# Laravel 5 Add custom attribute in paginate()

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, models

I want to add custom attribute in model. i put:

```
// app/models/xxxModel.php
public function getTituloAttribute()
{
    return 'Cotizacion número: ' . $this->attributes['number'];
}
```

And then in Controller:

```
    $quotations         = AdminQuotations::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate()->toArray();
```

And i want to use xxxmodel->titulo in the view, but not appear this new attribute.

Thanks a lot, sory for my english.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a protected property named `appends` to append the list of attribute that are not from the database.

```
class AdminQuotations
{
    protected $appends = [
        'titulo'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, im sory,
only i delete the:  ->toArray()

and thats all, the code is good to add the custom attribute

Thanks!